# SelectOneMenu - I can get the value

Tags: jsf, backing-beans

I've got a problem with my Java EE code.
In my XHTML page i insert a SelectOneMenu component and i fill it thanks to my DB. But the problem is when i want to get its value tha value NULL is set instead of my SelectOneMenu. Here you can find it :

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="prenom" value="inscrireBean.prenom">
    <f:selectItems value="#{user.noms}" />
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="prenomMessage"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And here my backing bean :

```
package com.projet.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import com.projet.dao.UtilisateurDao;
import com.projet.entities.personnes;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class InscrireBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private personnes       utilisateur;
    private String prenom ;

    // Injection de notre EJB (Session Bean Stateless)
    @EJB
    private UtilisateurDao    utilisateurDao;

    // Initialisation de l'entité utilisateur
    public InscrireBean() {
        utilisateur = new personnes();
    }

    // Méthode d'action appelée lors du clic sur le bouton du formulaire
    // d'inscription
    public void inscrire() {
        utilisateur.setPrenom(prenom);
        utilisateurDao.creer( utilisateur );
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage( "Succès de l'inscription !" );
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( null, message );
    }

    public personnes getUtilisateur() {
        return utilisateur;
    }
}
```

In my database the value set is : NULL 
and when i use the Debug mod the value of prenom is : error(s) during the evaluation

I hope that someone could help me in my problem :)
Have a good day.

Comment: Where exactly did you learn that you have to use the syntax `value="inscrireBean.prenom"` ?

Comment: try #{beanName.property}--> in your case #{inscrireBean.prenom}, and is mandatory get/set by property.

Comment: Yes you right i'm so embarasing ^^ Thanks a lot !!